# Eclipse - failed to create buildconfig class Android 4.4 Ubuntu 13.04

Tags: android, eclipse, ubuntu

My IDE is:

**Eclipse IDE for Java Developers**
**Version**: Kepler Service Release 1
**Build id**: 20130919-0819

I'm used this for developer yesterday and it's Ok

Today I have this error:
    `Failed to create BuildConfig class`

I have tried everything but without success.

What can I do now ?

Comment: Have you tried cleaning the project and rebuilding?

Comment: I cleaning the Project....How to I rebuilding ?????

Comment: After cleaning, try running to see if the buildConfig generates.

Comment: buildConfig generates ????